# I wonder why my code is returning null in the condition

Tags: react-native

I have a function for a tinder-like app and this is returning me Null in the condition

```js
const hydratedValidRecommendation = (otherUser) => {
  var userSettings = user.settings;

  if (!userSettings) {
    userSettings = {
      distance_radius: "unlimited",
      //gender: 'none',
      // gender_preference: 'all',
      show_me: true,
      //age: 'sans limites',
      //poids: 'Sans limites',
    };
    let newUser = { ...user, settings: userSettings };

    userAPIManager.updateUserData(user?.id, newUser);
    dispatch(setUserData({ user: newUser }));
  }

  const myLocation = user.location;
  const myGenderPre =
    (userSettings && userSettings?.gender_preference) || "all";
  const appDistance = (userSettings &&
    userSettings.distance_radius &&
    userSettings.distance_radius.toLowerCase() != "unlimited" &&
    userSettings.distance_radius.split(" ")) || ["100000"];
  const distanceValue = Number(appDistance[0]);
  const { firstName, email, profilePictureURL, id } = otherUser;
  const defaultAvatar =
    "https://www.iosapptemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/empty-avatar.jpg";
  const gender = otherUser.settings ? otherUser.settings.gender : "none";
  const genderPre = otherUser.settings
    ? otherUser.settings.gender_preference
    : "all";
  const location = otherUser.location ? otherUser.location : "unlimited";
  const isNotCurrentUser = id != user.id;
  const hasNotBeenBlockedByCurrentUser =
    bannedUserIDs != null && !bannedUserIDs.includes(id);
  const hasPreviouslyNotBeenSwiped =
    swipes != null && !swipes.find((user) => user.id == id);

  const otherUserProfileIsPublic =
    otherUser.settings && otherUser.settings.show_me != null
      ? otherUser.settings.show_me === true
      : true;
  if (
    //firstName &&
    //firstName.length > 0 &&
    email &&
    profilePictureURL &&
    //profilePictureURL != defaultAvatar && // Uncomment this line if you don't want users with no avatar show up in the recommendations
    (location || appDistance == "100000") &&
    isNotCurrentUser &&
    hasPreviouslyNotBeenSwiped &&
    otherUserProfileIsPublic &&
    hasNotBeenBlockedByCurrentUser
  ) {
    console.log("dsqdsqdsqd", isNotCurrentUser);
    if (!location || !myLocation) {
      otherUser.distance = IMLocalized("> 100 km");

      return otherUser;
    }

    otherUser.distance = distance(
      location.latitude,
      location.longitude,
      myLocation.latitude,
      myLocation.longitude
    );

    const otherUserDistanceNumber = otherUser.distance.match(/\d+/);
    const isWithinDistanceRadius =
      otherUserDistanceNumber?.length > 0 &&
      otherUserDistanceNumber[0] <= distanceValue;
  }

  return null;
};
```

The rest of the code is here because it's linked to the function on the top

```js
const getMoreRecommendationsIfNeeded = async () => {
  if (isLoadingRecommendations.current || hasConsumedRecommendationsStream) {
    return;
  }

  isLoadingRecommendations.current = true;

  try {
    const documentSnapshots = await recommendationRef.current.get();
    const docs = documentSnapshots.docs;

    if (docs.length > 0) {
      // Get the last visible recommendation document and construct a new query starting at this document,
      recommendationRef.current = usersRef
        .orderBy("id", "desc")
        .startAfter(documentSnapshots.docs[docs.length - 1])
        .limit(recommendationBatchLimit);

      // Filter out invalid recommendations and update the UI data source
      const newRecommendations = filteredAndHydratedRecommendations(docs);

      isLoadingRecommendations.current = false;

      if (newRecommendations.length > 0) {
        setRecommendations([...recommendations, ...newRecommendations]);
      } else {
        getMoreRecommendationsIfNeeded();
      }
    } else {
      isLoadingRecommendations.current = false;
      setHasConsumedRecommendationsStream(true);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert(error);
    isLoadingRecommendations.current = false;
  }
};

const filteredAndHydratedRecommendations = (docs) => {
  const hydratedRecommendations = docs?.map((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data().email);
    console.log("return", hydratedValidRecommendation(doc.data()));
    return hydratedValidRecommendation(doc.data());
  });

  return hydratedRecommendations.filter((recommendation) => {
    recommendation != null;
  });
};
```

Sorry, I'm in trouble explaining my code because it's a customer who did it like that and I'm supposed to debug it if you can try to figure it out with me it would be cool :)

Comment: What do you mean by "returning me Null in the condition"? And there are multiple conditions in that code. which one does cause an error?

Comment: If you mean "why does `hydratedValidRecommendation`" return `null`: This is because seemingly non of the other conditions, that would lead to a different return statement is met. Why? Nobody can tell without data. You will have to debug step by step ...

Comment: Especially, the only possibility for that function to return something different from `null` is, if the condition  `if (!location || !myLocation)` is met. Because that's the only return statement which returns a value different from null (if `otheruser` is different from null)

Comment: Yeah that's what i was thinking but the ting is how do i put all this const in the return cause the code is working with props and all the condition are good